# To find the starting and ending points in a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've a table (T1) with one column (C1) with the below values

```
1
2
3
5
6
8
9
10
```

I want the output to print the continuous sequences with start and ending points like below.

```
1-3
5-6
8-10
```

Could you please help?

Any Database is fine.

Comment: if you could provide the logic behind the output that would be useful

Comment: The sequence starts with value 1 and breaks after 3(4 is missing). So 1 and 3 are my start and ending point. The sequence next starts at 5 and breaks after 6(7 is missing). So 5-6 are my start and ending points. It goes on like that

Comment: Set the tag of the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle: sample data first, while code you really need begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with t1 (c1) as
  2    (select 1 from dual union all
  3     select 2 from dual union all
  4     select 3 from dual union all
  5     select 5 from dual union all
  6     select 6 from dual union all
  7     select 8 from dual union all
  8     select 9 from dual union all
  9     select 10 from dual
 10    )
 11  select min(c1), max(c1)
 12  from (select c1, c1 - row_number() over (order by c1) rn
 13        from t1
 14       )
 15  group by rn
 16  order by rn;

   MIN(C1)    MAX(C1)
---------- ----------
         1          3
         5          6
         8         10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query. I have tested it with SQL Server, but I think it will work without modifications in Oracle:

```
create table t1(c1 int);

insert into t1
 select *
   from (values(1),(2),(3),(5),(6),(8),(9),(10))t(x);

select case when count(*) >1 then 
             concat(min(c1),'-',max(c1)) 
            else concat(max(c1),'')
        end as concat_cs
from (
        select c1
               ,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1 asc)  as rnk
               ,c1 - ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c1 asc) as grp
          from t1
     )x
group by x.grp
```

Output

```
concat_cs
1-3
5-6
8-10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with stab as (
   select 1 as val from dual union all
   select 2 as val from dual union all 
   select 3 as val from dual union all
   select 5 as val from dual union all 
   select 6 as val from dual union all 
   select 8 as val from dual union all 
   select 9 as val from dual union all 
   select 10 as val from dual union all 
   select 13 as val from dual union all 
   select 15 as val from dual union all 
   select 16 as val from dual union all 
   select 17 as val from dual union all 
   select 18 as val from dual union all 
   select 19 as val from dual union all 
   select 23 as val from dual 
),sq2 as(
  select 
    row_number() over(order by 1) as rownumber,val
  from stab
)
  select 
    a.val,b.val
  from sq2 A
  join sq2 b on b.rownumber  = a.rownumber+2 
  where mod(A.rownumber,3)=1
```

Output:

```
         1          3
         5          8
         9         13
        15         17
        18         23
```